# Using PHP Sessions in a quiz

Tags: php, forms, session

I have made a yes/no quiz where the game tries to guess what creature you are thinking of based on these questions, there are only 16 possible answers.

What I am trying to is make it so that if the user closes the site part-way through the quiz then when they return to the quiz they will taken to the same question they left off on. Below is what I have done so far but it doesn't work properly (see for yourself at http://s504518.brunelweb.net/Creatures.php) You must answer yes to the first question and then close the browser as I have only done a session for that question so far. Here is part of the what I have done so far

```
//These are used for saving the session
 $q2 = "<div class='questions'><p>{$questions[0][0]}</p></div>";
 $q3 = "<div class='questions'><p>{$questions[0][1]}</p></div>";

 $f2 = "<div class='questions'><form method ='GET' action='Creatures.php'>
     <input type='submit' name='answer1' value='Yes' class='buttons' />
     <input type='submit' name='answer1' value='No' class='buttons' />
     </form></div>";
 $f3 = "<div class='questions'><form method ='GET' action='Creatures.php'>
     <input type='submit' name='answer2' value='Yes' class='buttons' />
     <input type='submit' name='answer2' value='No' class='buttons' />
     </form></div>";

//If start button has not been pressed, display nothing
if (!isset($_POST['start'])){

} //If start button has been pressed, display questions
else
{
//Display the first question
echo $firstquestion;
     echo "<div class='questions'><form method ='GET' action='Creatures.php'>
     <input type='submit' name='yes1' value='Yes' class='buttons' />
     <input type='submit' name='no1' value='No' class='buttons' />
     </form></div>";
}
//Question 2
if (isset($_SESSION['form']))
{
echo $_SESSION['question'];
echo $_SESSION['form'];
}
else{
if ($_GET['yes1']) //If answer to Q1 is yes then display this
{
echo "<div class='questions'><p>{$questions[0][0]}</p></div>";
showquestion(1);
$_SESSION['question'] = $q2;
$_SESSION['form'] = $f2;
}
}
```

What I am trying to achieve here is, if a session has already been set then display the question and form from that session and if it hasn't display nothing until they click the start button. I'm not sure why it doesn't work properly and any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: A session gets destroyed when you close the website. Look into using cookies. http://php.about.com/od/advancedphp/qt/php_cookie.htm

Comment: I know it can be done as I have seen it done before, go to http://pbambridge.brunelweb.net/aw/expert.php

Comment: Are you sure that that's using a session?

Comment: No I know it can be done, I'm just saying try using Cookies instead of `$_SESSION` http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_cookies.asp

Comment: I NEED to use PHP sessions as I need to demonstrate that I know how to use them (which I don't... entirely) and I don't know for sure that he  used sessions but he said he did and I believe him, he wouldn't tell me to do it if he did it a different way himself.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a session with session_start(), put this into the first line of php:

```
session_start();
```

As php.net tells me, it will also use already generated sessions. Just be shure you have no html-output before starting the session

Comment: Oh damit, I'm just to tired to read... Use session_name("quiz") before session_start to create and get the specified session back

Comment: I have done that and it almost working now, but instead of the saved question changing to the next one it just stays there and next question appears underneath.